# Why i get difference in output when i print this code directly and after storing in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

when I give

```
ps -aux|grep -w 'bash'|grep -v 'grep'|awk '{print $2}'
```

I get output:

```
32356
```

Also when I give

```
echo $(ps -aux|grep -w 'bash'|grep -v 'grep'|awk '{print $2}')
```

i get output:

```
32356 32551
```

**Why there is difference in the  outputs?**

Comment: Likely you just opened another bash terminal somewhere. `ps aux` will get **all** your processes. This is not a robust way to detect your `bash` process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that the `$(...)` syntax starts a subshell. So the `ps` command inside those parentheses will find both your current shell (which you can get using `$$`, as @tink said his their answer), and the subshell that is invoked by the parentheses.

Using `ps fux` and rediction into a file, you can see exactly what is happening:

```
ps fux | grep -w bash > a
cat a
me  11603  0.1  0.0 114408  3728 pts/1    Ss   13:37   0:00  \_ -bash
me  11955  0.0  0.0 103348   872 pts/1    S+   13:41   0:00      \_ grep -w bash

echo $(ps fux | grep -w bash > b)
cat b
me  11603  0.1  0.0 114408  3728 pts/1    Ss+  13:37   0:00  \_ -bash
me  11981  0.0  0.0 114408  2304 pts/1    S+   13:41   0:00      \_ -bash
me  11983  0.0  0.0 103348   872 pts/1    S+   13:41   0:00          \_ grep -w bash
```

Although @tink gave you a good solution, I hope this answer helps understand what is happening.

Comment: @AllenJohnson Can you show an example of a firefox process you'd be looking for? If you provide the output of `ps` showing the process you want to find the pid for, it would be easier to understand your exact requirements. (This is answering a comment you deleted, not sure if the question is still relevant...)

Comment: Nice  Explanation

Comment: Now i thought that for any other process there is no problem, grep wont take the subshell value in that case .Only situation is when i want to find bash process id.That can be solved by his method.So no problem

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you're after the `pid` of the shell you're currently running.  That's best achieved with

```
echo $$  # which is a bash special variable
```

Comment: Great effort tink,  what i want is not only for bash but for every other process

Comment: So, to clarify: you want ALL pids but the ones spawned from the current shell?